# How to line up a label to the right of a styled checkbox

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to align a label with my styled checkbox.  I'm using [this spiffy CSS toggle switch as a styled checkbox](http://callmenick.com/2014/05/13/css-toggle-switch-examples/).  I have the following HTML:

```
<label>
  <input id="test" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="test"></label>
  testlabel
</label>
```

Along with that, I have the following CSS:

```
input.cmn-toggle-round + label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  -o-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before, input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -ms-border-radius: 30px;
  -o-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round + label:after {
  width: 29px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  -ms-border-radius: 100%;
  -o-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.4s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.4s;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #8ce196;
}
input.cmn-toggle-round:checked + label:after {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

The result has the text from the label placed directly below the checkbox, rather than to the right of it.  Here is a screenshot as an example:
[image: this is the output]

My question is simple.  Why is this happening?  How can I line up the label to be on the right of the checkbox instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text label is being pushed beneath the toggle because it's set to display: block. You could either:
1. Change this to display: inline-block, which would bring the inline text up next to it on the right.
2. Leave display:block, but add float: left to your toggle, so that the text comes up next to it.

You'll just have to add margin/padding to the text as necessary; you'll probably want to wrap it in a  or other element so you can style it more easily.

Comment: Adding float: left to my toggle gives some interesting behaviour when you have multiple toggles in a row.  [Here is an example](http://imgur.com/Yzr6Xb2)

Comment: Yes, that can happen. It would help if you posted your actual code, but just looking at it, I think if each label pair (the toggle and the text) are wrapped in their own block-level element (like a div), that should prevent this from happening. If you want the toggles and their labels to all appear horizontally in line, then you'll want to set the wrapper elements for each pair to `float: left` as well.

Comment: Right.  Wrapping each individually in a div helped.  Curious why that makes a difference, but happy to have a resolution.  This has been bugging me for a few hours :) Thank you

Comment: It was because the text label heights were shorter than the toggle heights. When you set an element to `float: left`, it will "float" as far top/left as the surrounding elements will allow. Because the text label didn't take up as much vertical space as the toggle, the subsequent toggle would push up against the previous text label and then to the left, and would hit the previous toggle, creating the stagger effect. Wrapping the text label/toggle pairs in a div ensures that both are the same height, so you there's no longer a space for subsequent elements to snug up against.

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense.  So, the div pads it out so the subsequent toggles can't float up against it.  Thanks for the bonus info!